# How to Query a Postgresql table with spaces in java

Tags: java, database, postgresql

So when I gather user input and use that value within a SELECT statement, It it only reads the the last string after space. So, for example if I search for 'New York', only 'York' will show. Maybe I can do a LIKE '%?', Then store all the values returned in an array and match the user input exactly with the value of the city name in the array and return it, but there must be a way to just return what i want from the query.

My table:

```
   public void createTable(){
        try{
            Statement stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cities (" +
                    "name varchar(50)," +
                    "population int," +
                    "latitude double precision," +
                    "longitude double precision" +
                    ")");
            System.out.println("Cities table created.");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

here is my function that queries

```
    public void readLine(String city){
        try{
            String sqlLike = "SELECT * FROM cities " +
                    "WHERE cities.name = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement(sqlLike);
            ps.setString(1, city);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.print(" " + rs.getString(2));
                System.out.print(" " + rs.getString(3));
                System.out.print(" " + rs.getString(4) + "\n");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Here is my Main that prompts user for input. No validation yet so don't mind that

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
        Database dbConn = new Database();
        dbConn.createTable();
//        dbConn.insertIntoDatabase();
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String citySelect = "";

        while(!citySelect.equals("exit".toLowerCase())){
            System.out.print("Please enter the name of the city in question: ");
            citySelect = scnr.next();
            dbConn.readLine(citySelect.toLowerCase());
        }

    }
```

Any Advice guys?

Comment: that's how Scanner behaves, it tokenizes by blank, so you get one query for "New" and one for "York". Since there is no city named "New" only "York" seems to be left.

Comment: _Any Advice guys?_ Try method [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) instead of `next()`, as in: `citySelect = scnr.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the database table or query, which will have no problem storing or retrieving city names containing spaces.

The problem is that the **Scanner** class by default uses space as a delimiter ([from the class' Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

So every time you call Scanner's next() you get the next string token according to the delimiter.

In order to change the default behaviour, set a different delimiter for the Scanner (potentially something that will not occur in your results). For instance, in your code make the following call before the while loop of your main method:

```
scnr.useDelimiter(", ");
```

Comment: Right I understand now. But for this scenario I just had to use scnr. nextLine(). In the docs as defined => nextLine() "Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped". I just wanted to record the value on the line regardless of whitespaces.